# What's the best way to send multiple requests to a server?

Tags: node.js, request, discord.js

first off, I am writing in node.js using modules discord.js, request, and request-promise. I am having trouble sending a ton (about 70) different requests to a server. I keep getting the same result from the different requests. `'https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/' + entry.uuid + '/names'` That is the request I am making, I have a forEach loop going through a list of urls like this.
Here is my code for the requests:

```
function getNames() {
    count = 0;
    msg.channel.send("Started getting Names");
    urls.forEach(function() {
        request(urls[count], function(err, res, body) {
            if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
                const obj = JSON.parse(body);
                names[count] = body[0].name;
                msg.channel.send(urls[count] + ", Username " + count + ": " + obj[0].name);
            } else {
                msg.channel.send("Username Error: " + err);
            }
        });
        count++;
    });
    while (true) {
        if (names.length != urls.length) {
            msg.channel.send("Finished getting Names");
            console.log("UUIDs:" + urls.join(", "));
            console.log("Names:" + names.join(", "));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The `msg.channel.send` commands I am using for debugging my code (discord.js if you are curious).
Now, my problem is this: `msg.channel.send(urls[count] + ", Username " + count + ": " + obj[0].name);` always gives me a new url but the same username as the first request (`obj[0].name` is always the same). So, say I have 3 **different** urls the first URLs username is Evan, second is Jack, third is John. When I run the code, my names array would be `["Evan", "Evan", "Evan"]` instead of `["Evan", "Jack", "John"]`. I think it is because my code is not waiting for the request result before moving on.
I am sure there is probably many better ways of doing this, I would appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo: https://repl.it/@kallefrombosnia/OldfashionedQuintessentialConditions

```
// request package is deprecated so I use this one
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

// random mojang acc's
const urls = [
  'https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/7125ba8b1c864508b92bb5c042ccfe2b/names',
  'https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/97f2453a361b44fa9312c496b67f24fc/names',
  'https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/ac224782efff4296b08cdbde8e47abdb/names',
];


getNames = () => {

  let names = [];
  let round = 0;

  // parse trough urls
  urls.forEach((url, index) => {

    // fetch url info
    fetch(url).then(res =>

      // json convert
      res.json())

      .then(jsonBody => {

        // iteration level
        round++;

        // add name to the array
        names.push(jsonBody[0].name);

        // print some info about user
        console.log(urls[index] + ", Username " + index + ": " + jsonBody[0].name);

        // if this is last round and number of names is same as urls number print all info about users
        if (round === urls.length && names.length === urls.length) {

          console.log("Finished getting Names");
          console.log("UUIDs:" + urls.join(", "));
          console.log("Names:" + names.join(", "));
        }

      })
  })
}

getNames();
```